# Sync Account is not created under Settings > Accounts

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-settings

I have created the app with the Sync Adapter which creates an account under Settings > Account. It was working fine in all the phones and tablets.

Now I have received a bug saying it is not working in the Android Nougat, means  the sync account under Setting > Accounts is not created.

Also it is working perfectly in the Android Nougat and Android Oreo having stock android, but it is not working in the phones like Redmi running on Android N MIUI and some of the Micromax phones.

I have seen other apps like linkedin, Facebook are easily creating the sync accounts in the same devices but not my app.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mi's Security app might be blocking the service. Check it, and enable the service. It may fix the issue

Comment: Thank u.. You are right, Auto Run is disabled in the Mi Security App. After enabling it's working fine. You saved my time.